# insert wordpress custom field content into wordpress post using SQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need a sql query that will allow me to take the contents of a Wordpress custom field and insert them into the existing post (post_content).  I have thousands of record that I need to do this with.

My limited SQL knowledge isnt good enough to figure this out since the the custom fields are stored in the "wp_postmeta" table and the post content is stored in the "wp_posts" table.

Thanks

Comment: If you have a specific question about your select statement you can ask about it. But this is not the place to do this for you. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to (and you most definitely don't WANT to) use SQL to do what you want.

Since you haven't actually tried anything yet, you should take a look at [Update Post Meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) if you want to make sure all of your tables are populated correctly, and everything is referenced properly according to Wordpress' standards.

If you run into any issues with writing the actual code to handle this, please open a new question and show us what you've tried.

Good luck.